# Expanding a function into a power series

Tags: calculus, power-series

I was given this function
$$\frac{x-2}{1-x}$$

around x zero = 2

I'm not sure how to do it, i called x-2 = t,
so 1-x = -t-1

and i moved on from there..

Is there another way to do this question?

Comment: That seems a simple and straightforward way to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{x-2}{1-x+2-2}=\frac{x-2}{-1-(x-2)}=-\frac{x-2}{1+(x-2)}$$

Use geometric series for $1/(1-(x-2))$

Answer (score 0):

By setting $t=x-2$, you get, as $|t|=|x-2|<1$,
$$
\frac{x-2}{1-x}=\frac{x-2}{-1-(x-2)}=-\frac{t}{1+t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}t^{n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}(x-2)^{n+1},
$$ and you are done.

Comment: $-\frac{t}{1+t} = -t\frac{1}{1+t} = -t(1-t+t^2-t^3+t^4\cdots$